# Phonegap and PhotoSwipe in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, photoswipe

I have a problem using Phonegap and PhotoSwipe; I want to call a ajax page that contains the photo gallery; but in this case PhotoSwipe doesn't work. It Seems very easy.

Thanks for the help

Henry

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#photo', function(){

    console.log("photo1");

    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var options = {};
            $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe(options);

        });


    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

});
```

This is the simple html:

```
 <!-- Start of page - GALLERY -->
 <div data-role="page" id="photo">

     <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
         <a href="#page4" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a><h1>ABC</h1>
     </div><!-- /header -->

     <div data-role="content">

         <ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">

             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src=""/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 005" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src=""/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 006" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src=""/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 007" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src=""/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 008" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src=""/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 009" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="/img/page/155/icon4.jpg" rel="external"><img src="/img/page/155/icon.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>
         </ul>

     </div><!-- /content -->

 </div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is extremely broad.

Comment: Sorry Danny; when I click an photo from the list, the image is loading as a external page without Photoswipe effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I click an photo from the list, the image is loading as a
>   external page without Photoswipe effects.

this indicates that photoswipe is not being fired. Try removing `document.ready` event, because `pageshow` event is fired after document is ready.

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#photo', function(){

    console.log("photo1");

    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
        var options = {};
        $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe(options);

    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2CyCB/) is a simplified example of your code that works.

Comment: Thank keune; unfortunately your solution doesn't work. The behavior is the same. 
I add 2 console.log:
[code]
 $(document).on('pageshow','#photo', function(){
 console.log("photo1");   
 (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
  var options = {};
  console.log("photo2");
 $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe(options);
console.log("photo3");
}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
});
When the page is loaded console.log("photo3") don't appears.

Comment: I received this error: TypeError: $(...).photoSwipe is not a function
I don't know how to resolve this problem

Comment: UPDATE @keune: 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Document</title>

<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>

</head>

generates this error: TypeError: d is not a function - 

Is there a conflict?

Comment: if possible, use jquery 1.6.4 also check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2CyCB/1/

Comment: Thanks! Solved! I add the file klass.min.js in my script and now works perfectly! Many thanks ;-)